# CodeBlocks cannot find shared libraries even when search paths are setup

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, ld, archlinux

I have a very basic C++ project in code blocks that makes use of `glfw.so` and two other libraries that are compiled to .so files from another project, `libHorde3D.so` and `libHorde3DUtils.so`. The latter are placed in the project root folder, while glfw is somewhere in my `/usr/lib` (I think).

I have added  the project folder to the linker and compiler search paths in code blocks. I have added the `libHorde3D.so` and `libHorde3DUtils.so` as well as `glfw.so` to the Link Libraries in the Linker Settings tab. I thought that this would be enough based on the previous similar questions here on stackoverflow.

However when I press build:

```
ld cannot find -lHorde3D.so
ld cannot find -lHorde3DUtils.so
ld cannot find -lglfw.so
```

My system is Arch Linux 64 and I am using GCC.
I also tried bopying `libHorde3D.so` and `libHorde3DUtils.so` in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64` with no success.

P.S. All search paths are copied across the Debug and Release target.

Comment: you should not put ".so" as linker flag. use it like -llibrary..

Comment: Side note: Set CodeBlocks option to show full command line during project build, this helps to solve such kind of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say, if the library name is `libmylibrary.so`, then linker option to link against that library would look like `-lmylibrary`. Note that `lib` prefix and `.so` suffix are not there — they are added automatically by the linker. In your case it seems like you specified the wrong name. Try removing `.so` from it, that should solve the problem.

Here is a simple demonstration of how to trigger the failure by making a similar mistake:

```
$ echo 'int main() { return 0; }' > test.c
$ gcc -o test ./test.c -lc
$ gcc -o test ./test.c -lc.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

The first command succeeds and the second one (with incorrect library name) fails.

Comment: Both replies are correct and fixed my stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You must not pass ".so". The linker options are

```
-lHorde3D -lHorde3DUtils -lglfw
```

This way the linker will search for "libHorde3D.so" etc. in the library path(s).